# Remove all traces of attributes

Tags: attributes, maintenance

If I remove an attribute from an attribute set, I notice that data is still contained in the product. How do I remove all this old data?

Comment: will you please provide details about how you see the old data, what you had done to get this?

Comment: 1.)Remove that attribute from attribute set and save. 2.)Use software like Flagbit or programmatically change the attribute set. Either way keeps the old values in the table.

Comment: Do you try it do it manually to remove attribute, is it giving same results?

Comment: In this particular instance I'm not removing the attribute, but programmatically changing the attribute set. So what is happening is that the old value are left in the table from attribute set now not related to the entity_id of the product. That is what I'm trying to find the best way to remove.